# How to set a control to be selected by default?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How can I specify an EditText to be selected by default when the dialog box in which it loads is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

also

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
```